# What are the steps to deploy of laravel project on Debian?

Tags: laravel-5, deployment, debian, apache2

I developed my Laravel Project on Windows using xampp. So I need to deploy this project in a Debian server. In this server, I've already installed apache2, php7.3 and composer. All fine. I transfered my project from Windows to Debian by ssh. Inside the project I had run composer update. But when I try to accesss via browser, I got 404 page not found error. Do I miss some step? Someone could please help me?

Comment: You have to set proper permissions on folders and need to make sure that mod-rewrite is enabled on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to create an apache config to the new project:

Something like these:
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/meuprojeto.conf

Edit this file with the follow code:
    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/meuprojeto/public
    ServerName seudominio.com
    
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Config apache service to be sure it's enable: 
sudo systemctl stop apache2.service
sudo systemctl start apache2.service
sudo systemctl enable apache2.service

Final steps:

Enable rewrite
sudo a2enmod rewrite

Enable your project config
sudo a2ensite meuprojeto.conf

Disable default config (default apache page)
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf

Restart apache service
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service